# Getting Time Zone from Lat Long Coordinates?

Tags: python, timezone, latitude-longitude, geonames

I am trying to get the time zones for latitude and longitude coordinates but am having a few problems
The mistakes are probably very basic

I have a table in a database with around 600 rows. Each row contains a lat long coordinate for somewhere in the world
I want to feed these co-ordinates into a function and then retrieve the time zone. The aim being to convert events which have a local time stamp within each of these 600 places into UTC time

I found a [blog post](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/04/converting-addresses-to-timezones-in.html) which uses [a piece of code](https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/2288222) to derive timezones from geographical coordinates.

When I try to run the code, I get the error `geonames is not defined`. I have applied for an account with geonames.

I think I have just saved the function file in the wrong directory or something simple. Can anyone help

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Converts latitude longitude into a time zone
# REF: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/2288222
# REF: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/04/converting-addresses-to-timezones-in.html
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

geonames_client = geonames.GeonamesClient('Username_alpha')
geonames_result = geonames_client.find_timezone({'lat': 48.871236, 'lng': 2.77928})
user.timezone = geonames_result['timezoneId']
```

Comment: You don't seem to have *imported* `geonames`. Add a `import geonames` line?

Comment: related: [Get Timezone from City in Python/Django](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16505501/4279), see [`pytzwhere` example in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16519004/4279).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
import geonames
geonames_client = geonames.GeonamesClient('demo')
geonames_result = geonames_client.find_timezone({'lat': 48.871236, 'lng': 2.77928})
print geonames_result['timezoneId']
```

Output:

```
'Europe/Paris'
```

Comment: @manuel_riel what library is this ...import geonames?

Comment: Just a Python package that wraps geonames.org. It's in Pypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geonames/

Comment: The package you linked do doesn't seem to have a GeonamesClient class. Are you maybe using a different package?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid.

Comment: The library mentioned is not working under Linux. The Code is only supporting python2 and there are Hardcoded windows paths.

Comment: anyone revisit this recently and have a perspective on what may be the best library to use to convert lat/long to timezones?

Answer (score 41):

With tzwhere and pytz:

```
import datetime
import pytz
from tzwhere import tzwhere

tzwhere = tzwhere.tzwhere()
timezone_str = tzwhere.tzNameAt(37.3880961, -5.9823299) # Seville coordinates
timezone_str
#> Europe/Madrid

timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone_str)
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
timezone.utcoffset(dt)
#> datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
```

Comment: It worked as an off-line solution we needed.
Although some may encounter an error: 
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants when importing tzwhere.

This helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23057508/3699126

Comment: doesnt work in mac os x sierra and python 2.7

Comment: Any additional detail? Message error? Can you try with Python 3?

Comment: no error, `None` is returned calling `tzNameAt` method

Comment: This worked for me in High Sierra and Python 2.7

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz What were the arguments of your call to tzNameAt? If you still can find them. Maybe it's normal that some coordinates make tzNameAt() return None?

Comment: For those facing this error in Mac OS: AttributeError: 'tzwhere' object has no attribute 'tzwhere' replace tzwhere = tzwhere.tzwhere() with tz = tzwhere.tzwhere(), use timezone_str = tz.tzNameAt(37.3880961, -5.9823299) in the next line.

Comment: `tzwhere ` appears to not be available in Python 3, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019641/using-tzwhere-module-in-python-3)

Comment: very strange: for me it works the first time then if a call again tzwhere.tzwhere() I get: AttributeError: 'tzwhere' object has no attribute 'tzwhere'

Answer (score 25):

I was able to do a lookup suitable for my purposes using [timezonefinder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timezonefinder):

```
import datetime
import timezonefinder, pytz

tf = timezonefinder.TimezoneFinder()

# From the lat/long, get the tz-database-style time zone name (e.g. 'America/Vancouver') or None
timezone_str = tf.certain_timezone_at(lat=49.2827, lng=-123.1207)

if timezone_str is None:
    print("Could not determine the time zone")
else:
    # Display the current time in that time zone
    timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone_str)
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    print("The time in %s is %s" % (timezone_str, dt + timezone.utcoffset(dt)))
```

There's a discussion of the methods of timezonefinder and its limitations in the documentation linked from [its pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timezonefinder).

`timezonefinder` and `pytz` can be found in the `pip` packages of the same name.

Comment: I haven't done a comprehensive test with multiple input coordinates, so I can't speak to the accuracy, but speed-wise timezonefinder is _much_ faster than tzwhere.  For me, at least.

Comment: This is the most up to date answer here, but for posterity, it really is worth looking at this link which is regularly updated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
lat = 48.871236 ## your latitude
lon = 2.77928 ## your longitude

url = "http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?formatted=true&lat={}&lng={}&username=demo".format(lat,lon)

r = requests.get(url) ## Make a request
return r.json()['timezoneId'] ## return the timezone
```

Comment: It works great. However, is there any hit limits for the use of this webservice?

Comment: This is what I received ```{'status': {'message': 'the daily limit of 20000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.', 'value': 18}}``` :)

Comment: With python 3.8 for me the error is `KeyError: 'timezoneId'`