# Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants

Tags: python, shapely

I use Python in Fedora 19. I wanted to run the following line:

```
import shapely.geometry
```

but the following error appears:

```
OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']
```

I installed the package Shapely, and the following two libraries:

- glibc-2.17-4.fc19.i686.rpm
- geos-3.3.8-2.fc19.i686.rpm.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: for Centos7 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097501/centos-libgeos-repository-missing yum install geos-devel

Answer (score 175):

Installed shapely using pip, and had the same problem. So I went ahead and installed it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
```

And it worked. I'm running Ubuntu, so if you're on Fedora, you should run:

```
sudo yum install geos-devel
```

On MACOS you can run:

```
brew install geos
```

Comment: On Fedora, it should be `sudo yum install geos-devel`

Comment: on mac OS `brew install geos`

Comment: If installing on ARM such as AWS Graviton2 instances (e.g. t4g instances) you might need `sudo yum install geos.aarch64 geos-devel.aarch64`

Comment: Thanks, my good friend!!! This saved my life and solved my issue with poetry install and lib shapely

Answer (score 9):

set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then run python

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to/geos/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

python mytest.py
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using Linux (Red Hat) and I got this error:

OSError: /home/[user]/.conda/envs/ox/lib/libgeos_c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**What works for me:**

```
conda install geos
```

Answer (score 6):

Shapely [loads geos via ctypes](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/geos.py).

Try this in your python and see if you get anything:

```
from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library('geos_c')
```

If it doesn't work, then your geos installation is probably messed up. According to [this](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20517538/dir/fedora_19/com/geos-3.3.8-2.fc19.i686.rpm.html), your geos should be in `/usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1`. Is your library actually there?

Comment: No result means that python didn't find the library (it returned `None`). On linux, python uses `/sbin/ldconfig -p` to find libraries (you can run that command and look for libgeos). I would guess that your geos RPM is missing a dependency or didn't get installed properly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I ran
`from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library('geos_c')`
And it returned `'libgeos_c.so.1'` so it looks like it's there...

Comment: For me, it returned something like: C:\Anaconda3\envs\my_env\Library\bin\geos_c.dll.

As I could observe, the libgeos_c.so.1 was not presente within the bin directory, only this 'dll' file.

Answer (score 5):

In ubuntu, the following commands should take care of it.
It all goes down to the following packages.

(Original 2017)

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-c1 libgeos-3.4.2
```

**EDIT:** (updated versions 2020)

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-3.7.1
```

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora install geos and geos-devel

```
sudo yum install geos geos-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Anaconda like I am and ran into this, copy the libgeos* files from /usr/lib to the anaconda/lib directory and try again... :)  Hopefully this saves someone else, cause I have spent hours on this.

Comment: Do you remember any other step you needed to take? I first installed it via brew and then copied the files to the anaconda lib folder as you suggested, but I'm still getting `OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'].` when I try to run my script. The strange part was that installing it via brew was enough for pip to start working.

Comment: I am using Anaconda on Ubuntu 16 and had similar error, even with libgeos-dev installed previously. The fix for me was `conda install geos` and after that, within my conda environment pip install shapely worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install geos
```

Just this installation solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem on Jupyter Notebook but when I used PyCharm I encountered this issue.
Tried multiple things windows on machine and the below troubleshooting steps fixed the issue

```
pip install geos
```

Go to PyCharm, File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter(Check you have the right path where your python.exe file is there)->Add [image]

Check that, on Virtualenv Environment -> Base Interpreter pointing to the right location where you have the python.exe

Same for System Interpreter->Interpreter
And also Pipenv Environment -> Base Interpreter

[image]

Make sure all are pointing to the right path. I encountered this problem as I have multiple IDE and hence multiple directories where python.exe is available.They were pointing to incorrect directories.

During the troubleshooting I also uninstalled and re installed  `conda install shapely`as I am pointing to Anaconda directory from PyCharm. Hope it helps.

Below link is also helpful https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#conda-package-manager

Answer (score 1):

I had still issues after installing geos. What solved it for me (macOS 13.1) was

```
sudo kmdir /opt/local
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/local/lib
```

to let Shapely find libgeos_c.dylib in one of the locations it was willing to look for it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093518/10093070)

Comment: Should be a better way to solve this, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and to solve it, you need to add the lib path to ld.so.conf file.

To do this, Open the file:

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf
```

add this line

```
/usr/local/lib
```

And then

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in alpine linux, and installed geos and the development libraries as follows

```
apk add geos geos-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have `macos`, you should run:

```
brew install geos
```

**Source distributions**

If you want to build Shapely from source for compatibility with other modules that depend on GEOS (such as cartopy or osgeo.ogr) or want to use a different version of GEOS than the one included in the project wheels you should first install the GEOS library, Cython, and Numpy on your system (using apt, yum, brew, or other means) and then direct pip to ignore the binary wheels.

```
pip install shapely --no-binary shapely
```

If you've installed GEOS to a standard location, the geos-config program will be used to get compiler and linker options. If geos-config is not on your executable, it can be specified with a GEOS_CONFIG environment variable, e.g.:

```
GEOS_CONFIG=/path/to/geos-config pip install shapely
```