# Shapely OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants []

Tags: python, shapely

I'm just trying to use the demo code. I run the following in Jupyter Notebook:

`from shapely.geometry import shape`

Which gives me the following:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cf5b4d0962ea> in <module>()
----> 1 from shapely.geometry import shape

/Users/hkwik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py in <module>()
      2 """
      3 
----> 4 from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
      5 from .geo import box, shape, asShape, mapping
      6 from .point import Point, asPoint

/Users/hkwik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py in <module>()
      7 from ctypes import pointer, c_size_t, c_char_p, c_void_p
      8 
----> 9 from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
     10 from shapely.ftools import wraps
     11 from shapely.geos import lgeos, ReadingError

/Users/hkwik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/coords.py in <module>()
      6 from ctypes import byref, c_double, c_uint
      7 
----> 8 from shapely.geos import lgeos
      9 from shapely.topology import Validating
     10 

/Users/hkwik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py in <module>()
     81         _lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=alt_paths)
     82 
---> 83     free = load_dll('c').free
     84     free.argtypes = [c_void_p]
     85     free.restype = None

/Users/hkwik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py in load_dll(libname, fallbacks, mode)
     59         raise OSError(
     60             "Could not find lib {0} or load any of its variants {1}.".format(
---> 61                 libname, fallbacks or []))
     62 
     63 _lgeos = None

OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants [].
```

However, if I run from the interpreter, everything is fine.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you attempted any solutions yet? It looks like an OSX exclusive problem, there are two issues on Github regarding this: https://github.com/carsonfarmer/python_geospatial/issues/3#issuecomment-49673981 & https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/394#issuecomment-235163776

Comment: Do you use virtual environment? How have you installed jupyter? Standard?

Comment: Have to say that @chrki comment looks like it is the answer - did you try it @Huey?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants Need to install libgeos-c1 libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-dev packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find library geos\_c or load any of its variants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants)

Answer (score 38):

I simply uninstalled Shapely and re-installed it to fix the issue.

```
python -m pip uninstall shapely

python -m pip install shapely
```

Comment: The wonders of technology never cease to amaze me.

Comment: Doing `pip3 install shapely --upgrade` is another solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You may try to reset the environment variable `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
```

[Source](https://github.com/carsonfarmer/python_geospatial/issues/3)

Comment: In my env the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH was set to $(HOME)/anaconda/lib. After changing it everything works well.

Answer (score 5):

Try this may help you:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall shapely
```

Answer (score 2):

For macOS users:

```
brew install geos
pip3 install shapely --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I fixed it:

```
apk add geos libc-dev musl-dev
pip install Shapely
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, only works after installing Shapely from the [shapely lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and executing the following command from Anaconda Prompt:

```sh
pip install Shapely-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl --force-reinstall
```

This forces a re-install of shapely.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a `conda update --all` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

@user2977865 and @anothernode are correct in their approach but it may not work for everyone.
By default, `shapely` will look for libraries in the `DYLD_PATH`.

I had it set to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/mysql/lib/`

But these libraries are placed in `/usr/lib`.

So I had to modify it as follows:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/:/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

Bonus note: Ensure that your environment variables have been set by restarting terminal and clearing cache of any IDEs you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue running code in aws lambda with the error message:

```
 OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants ['libc.musl-x86_64.so.1'].
```

I added `musl-dev` to my container installation and adapted the symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
```