# Error when importing geopandas OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants []

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas

I'm using Spyder with Anaconda and since MacOS last update (Big Sur 11.0.1), when doing
`import geopandas`, I get the following error:

```
OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants [].
```

There are several subjects on the matter (particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991765/shapely-oserror-could-not-find-lib-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants) and [this one](https://github.com/carsonfarmer/python_geospatial/issues/3)), that mainly recommends to reset the environment variable `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` by putting in the Terminal:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
```

However, here is what I get:

```
-bash: HOME: command not found
```

A `brew` or `pip` install didn't fix the problem either.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix this? Am I suppose to replace `$(HOME)` by something?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For references: I ended up reinstalling a new environment on Anaconda an it works but I wasn't able to fix the original problem.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same error and fixed it just by reinstalling Shapely:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall shapely
```

Comment: This solved the OS Error I was getting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. To fix the problem, use:

Change the Shapely package

https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/commit/a34ec59a7dc9089a71968c6871e29addd872ea3b

And then reinstall Xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```

The geos.py file and line number you need to modify will be in the log output that generated the OSError. Just look a few lines up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what do you mean by change the Shapely package? How should I do that?

Comment: You will need to look at your log in greater detail. I had the following information in my log. <path-to-conda-env>./lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 113, in <module>
    free = load_dll('c').free    .... modified this file per guidance of GitHub ref.