# Why can't i install the requirements.txt content?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

```
(env) user@name:~/$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Shapely==1.5.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached Shapely-1.5.13.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Failed `CDLL(libgeos_c.so.1)`
    Failed `CDLL(libgeos_c.so)`
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-p0Fy8v/Shapely/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "/tmp/pip-build-p0Fy8v/Shapely/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 167, in <module>
        fallbacks=['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-p0Fy8v/Shapely/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 161, in load_dll
        libname, fallbacks or []))
    OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-p0Fy8v/Shapely/
```

`requirements.txt` content :

```
Shapely==1.5.13
Flask==0.10.1
matplotlib==1.5.1
scipy==0.19.0
plumbum==1.6.2
numpy==1.12.1
ipython==5.5
Pillow==4.2.1
opencv-python==3.2.0.6
```

trying to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` but i keep on getting that error described above, i just installed python and pip and basically everything else after my format on linux 16.04 so not sure what's going wrong.

***Edit:***
I removed `Shapely==1.5.13` from the requirements.txt to test if it;s the issue and i got that error again `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oVKNjq/matplotlib/`

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62925/why-is-shapely-not-installing-correctly

Comment: looks like the Shapely is dependent on an application to be installed on OS. check this https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely#installing-shapely-16

Comment: Kindly check my edit, having the same issue with matplotlib..probably something wrong with my installation but i can't figure out what it is or fix it cause i uninstalled then reinstalled everything including python, the repo and the virtual environment.

Comment: do you have a compiler installed? seems to be the main issue, since `pip` usually compiles code when installing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find library geos\_c or load any of its variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants)