# Trouble installing geomeppy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble installing the package 'geomeppy' for editing IDFs. When running pip install geomeppy, it gives me the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'requirements.in'

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your pip, setuptools and wheel packages with the command and then retry installing geomeppy:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install geomeppy
```

**UPDATE:**

There are issues with the  latest version of geomeppy ( 0.4.12). Install previous one with the command:

```
pip install geomeppy==0.4.10
```

Also you will have to install geos_c library, see [Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants) for information of how to do this.