# OSError: Could not find geos_c.dll or load any of its variants

Tags: python, pip, installation, shapely

I'm trying to use shapley, and to use it for what I need it for, I have to import "from shapely import geometry" but I get the error OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll

I've tried to install "geos" via "pip install geos", didn't do anything: Requirement already satisfied

pip location: `C:\Users\skoft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe`

```
import shapely

from shapely import geometry

OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants ['C:\\Users\\skoft\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll'].
```

Comment: "pip install geos", didn't do anything what do you mean? error? didn't work? on windows pip is located in "scripts" subdir.

Comment: well, it didn't solve anything, and I'm not sure it's even related to this error I just tried something

Comment: can you type `where pip` and post the results?

Comment: C:\Users\skoft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe

Comment: damn that looks okay. And what is the output of `pip install geos` ? can you [edit] your question for that?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: geos in c:\users\skoft\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\skoft\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from geos) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\skoft\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from geos) (4.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\skoft\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from geos) (6.0.0)

Comment: sounds like a bug in shapely: search the dll in  c:\users\skoft\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages and if you found it, copy it in 'C:\\Users\\skoft\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll'

Comment: well I found a folder called geos and pasted it into lib, did not work. did not find any dll

Comment: Did you check here [Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants)?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Python 3.6 with Windows 10 in the Shapely library. I have downloaded the geos_c.dll file online and replaced it in the shapely dll folder that is in environment library. Replacement DLL folder

```
env\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs
```

[Download Link:](https://www.dll-files.com/geos_c.dll.html)

download geos_c.dll online, then put it into your lib address. it works for me

Answer (score 1):

On python 3.8.5 and windows 10. I meet the same error. Then **conda install shapely** solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. My import statement (**from shapely.geometry import Point**) successfully executed after I manually downloaded the **geo_c.dll** file from https://www.dll-files.com/geos_c.dll.html and placed it in the bin folder "**C:\Users....\Anaconda3\Library\bin**".

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it decided to install [Visual C++ for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145), because debugging the **site-packages\shapely\geos.py** file I noticed that the dll is being found but not loaded. Finally checking the **geos_c.dll** file dependencies I saw that it needed **MSVCP140.DLL**

Answer (score 0):

On python 3.6.5. and windows 10, installing GDAL through [osgeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) project and adding C:\OSGeo4W64\bin to the PATH variable solved the problem for me.