# OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants ['..\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll']

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6, shapely, geos

I'm having trouble with geos lib in python. I'm using an anaconda venv with **Python 3.6** on Windows 10. On one computer, it is running. So I exported the venv and installed the venv on another computer (which worked). But on the other computer, the same code is not running. I'm using **geos 3.8.0** and **shapely 1.6.4**. 
When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
*File "..\lib\site-packages\shapely\coords.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "..\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 130, in <module>
    os.path.join(sys.prefix, "Library", "lib", "geos_c.dll"),
  File "..\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 56, in load_dll
    libname, fallbacks or []))
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants ['..\\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll']*
```

I already tried:

- to reinstall the packages with conda-forge
- use other versions e.g.: geos 3.7.1 and shapely 1.7.0
- copied the geos_c.dll from ..\Library\bin (where it actually exists) to \Library\lib\
- changed the os.path.join in geos.py to  os.path.join(sys.prefix, "Library", "bin", "geos_c.dll")

Does anyone know, how to fix this problem so that I can run the code on both computers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find library geos\_c or load any of its variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. First it is about Fedora and not Windows. Second, the actual installation is actually working. But somehow, it is not possible shapely is not able to find/open geos_c.dll

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of the problem with installing the packages geos and shapely at base environment in anaconda. Maybe it helps someone else

Comment: I think it would be better if you posted this as an answer under the duplicate question I linked in the comment. It will be much easier for people to find this information then. If you do so, you could also delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using conda-forge, but it didn't work. However, it worked from the anaconda prompt after installing Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the VC_redist_x64.exe (or your equivalent) installed.  Apparently geos_c.dll users C+ elements.