# Using "tzwhere" module in Python 3

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to use the *tzwhere* module in Python 3. I want to enter in the coordinates of a location and return the timezone. However, when I run the following code:

```
!pip install pytz
!pip install tzwhere
import pytz
from tzwhere import tzwhere

tzwhere = tzwhere.tzwhere()
timezone_str = tzwhere.tzNameAt(37.3880961, -5.9823299)
print(timezone_str) #Europe/Madrid
```

I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/s.rayan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tzwhere/tz_world.json'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Which OS? Have you checked whether the file is actually missing?

Comment: What version of `tzwhere` did you install?

Comment: @MarkRansom I installed version 3.0.1 of tzwhere. Yes, the file is missing from the tzwhere directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like tzwhere works with Python 2 but not Python 3. I used the following code to convert coordinates to timezone:

```
!pip install geopy
from geopy import geocoders
    g = geocoders.GoogleV3()
    tz = str(g.timezone((55.7825, 12.3686)))
    time = timezone(tz)
```

Comment: It looks like this requires an internet connection and the lookup overhead that implies. Might be good for some people but not others.