# How to get corresponding pytz timezone name for a given location?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

For example, if the given location name is "Battle Creek", then, we may able able to find its corresponding timezone [details from this link](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/@4985153). This link says that this location belongs to EST.

But, it actually corresponds to pytz timezone name "America/Detroit" (Daylight Savings Schedule matches).

That is, Battle Creek -> EST -> "America/Detroit".

What is the way to find the relationship above?

Generally, How can I find corresponding pytz timezone name for any location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Time Zone from Lat Long Coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742045/getting-time-zone-from-lat-long-coordinates)

Comment: More importantly, is the city name "Battle Creek" all you have? [Wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Creek_(disambiguation)) there are three such named cities in the US.  Or do you have lat/lon coordinates? Or do you have a person's full address?

Comment: (Four cities actually.  I think you mean Battle Creek, Michigan in your example.)